# How to use static lib of openssl in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, openssl

I have a openssl static lib, has a bin include and lib folders. I am very new in windows and c++ programming. I am trying to ask how I should link those files and use them. such as include . I am using qt as my UI engine. How I can create a ssl socket with that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Qt, you can use Qt sockets. If Qt build with ssl support you can use [QSslSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qsslsocket.html)

For use openSSL directly you need to make visible openSSL include and lib dir for your project.

1. Use dynamicaly linked openSSL libraries. In this case you binaries try to find openSSL dlls at startup time and it can't load dlls application fails.
2. Use staticaly linked openSSl libraries. You must build openSSL staticaly (only libs no dlls). In this case you binaries doesn't need any openSSL dlls.

Comment: QSslSocket doesn't work very well since my data is very large. And it will create buffer overflow

Comment: @TonyHuang What sockets do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Using the static lib (using the header files  & linking to the lib) is similar to using any other static library in Windows. Please find below a link which details the procedure to create and use static libraries in an application. You can probably skip the create part and check only the using part.

[Creating & Using a Static Library in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Please note that the link talks from the perspective of VS2005.

For OpenSSL Programming examples you can refer to below:

[An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming Part - I](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4822)
[An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming Part - II](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5487)

Comment: I think I only need the libeay32.lib and ssleay32.lib in the lib folder. But how about the header files in the include folder and the dll files in the bin folder?